# Have problem configuring postgresql to rails on Ubuntu for WSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ubuntu

So I am using VS code on Ubuntu for WSL and fork a rails app from GitHub and when I try to run `rails db:set up`, it gives me this error:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'development_database' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

...traces...

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

And I tried to run `service postgresql status`,
I get `10/main (port 5432): down`.

And when I tried `dpkg -l | grep postgres`,
I got this back:

```
ii  postgresql                     10+190ubuntu0.1                    all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-10                  10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1             amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 10 server
ii  postgresql-client              10+190ubuntu0.1                    all          front-end programs for PostgreSQL (supported version)
ii  postgresql-client-10           10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1             amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 10
ii  postgresql-client-common       190ubuntu0.1                       all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common              190ubuntu0.1                       all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-contrib             10+190ubuntu0.1                    all          additional facilities for PostgreSQL (supported version)
```

Does that mean the problem is my server is not running? What should I do to run the server or create the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means your server is installed but not running. Try

```
service postgresql start
```

to start the server.

To check that your instance is running, try running

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres
```

Unless you have messed with your HBA configuration, that should connect you to your local `postgres` database (the default management DB) in role `postgres`.

Comment: Thanks! It does help me start the server. But I got this error:
`psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`
How can I authenticate myself? It never asks for my password as user postgres

Comment: Try `psql -d postgres` (which will try to access the DB as your linux username). If you are looking to understand this peer authentication stuff, check out the `pg_hba.conf` file, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html
Basically, you need to configure how users can connect to your DB.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and answer!

Comment: If you think my answer sufficiently addresses your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I just did sorry I forgot

Answer (score 0):

another quick way to fix this problem after starting the service is to run the following command

`sudo -u postgres psql`

likewise you connect to the default **postgres** database using the default user **"postgres"**

when you connect to "psql" create the "role" to allow you to connect without using the above credentials; expl:

`postgres=# CREATE ROLE username LOGIN SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION BYPASSRLS;`

those are the setting to create a superuser role, with the ability to connect to the default database **"postgres"** from the terminal like the following:

`username@yourserver:~$ psql postgres username`

or

`username@yourserver:~$ psql -U username -d postgres`